# Is there a cleaner way to subset correlation matrices?

Tags: r, correlation

I'm trying to search for highly correleated variables. My current code is:
`which(cor(numericData)<1&cor(numericData)>0.8,arr.ind = TRUE)` and this gives the output:

```
             row col
VarAlice     20   5
VarBob       11  10
VarCoco      10  11
Year          5  20
```

I have a number of problems with this:

1. To get this output, I've had to type out `cor(numericData)` more
   than once. I would've liked to type something like
   `0.8<cor(numericData)<1`.
2. The output given does not tell me the
   names of the variables that are correlated, meaning that I'll have
   to cross-reference this output with the massive original dataset.
3. Feeding this output back to `cor(numericData)`, i.e.
   `cor(numericData)[which(cor(numericData)<1&cor(numericData)>0.8,arr.ind= TRUE)]` is rather ugly and loses all information about what rows/columns the data came from, and just spits out the correlation coefficients.

Is there a better way? My ideal output would be a subset of `cor(numericData)` that shows only the relevant correlation coefficients and has the row/column names needed to identify them. In this specific case it's clear that `varAlice` appears to correlate strongly with `Year`, but that would have been much harder to see if I had 50 more variables, as my use case does.

Comment: Why can't you create an object `cor1 <- cor(numericData)` and then reuse that object `out <- which(cor1 < 1 & cor1 > 0.8, arr.ind = TRUE); data.frame(rn = row.names(cor1)[out[,1], colnames(cor1)[out[,2])`

Comment: @akrun That does tidy things up a bit, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better option is to create a temporary object with the `cor` output

```
tmp <- cor(numericData)
```

use that object to get the row/column index and subset the rows/columns

```
rc <- which(tmp < 1 & tmp > 0.8, arr.ind = TRUE)
out <- data.frame(rn = row.names(tmp)[rc[,1]], cn = colnames(tmp)[rc[,2]])
```

and remove the 'tmp'

```
rm(tmp)
```

---

Or another option without creating any temporary object is to convert to `data.frame` after creating the `table` class, and `subset` the data.frame based on the values in 'Freq' column

```
subset(as.data.frame.table(cor(numericData)), Freq < 1 & Freq > 0.8)
```

A reproducible example with `mtcars`

```
subset(as.data.frame.table(cor(mtcars)), Freq < 1 & Freq > 0.8)
#   Var1 Var2      Freq
#14 disp  cyl 0.9020329
#15   hp  cyl 0.8324475
#24  cyl disp 0.9020329
#28   wt disp 0.8879799
#35  cyl   hp 0.8324475
#58 disp   wt 0.8879799
```

Or with `between`

```
library(dplyr)
as.data.frame.table(cor(mtcars)) %>% 
     filter(data.table::between(Freq, 0.8, 1, incbounds = FALSE))
# Var1 Var2      Freq
#1 disp  cyl 0.9020329
#2   hp  cyl 0.8324475
#3  cyl disp 0.9020329
#4   wt disp 0.8879799
#5  cyl   hp 0.8324475
#6 disp   wt 0.8879799
```

Comment: So there's no trick for 0.8<Freq<1? That's a shame. At least Freq is easy to type.

Comment: @J.Mini If you are willing to use `between` from `dplyr`

Comment: @J.Mini in `R`, that syntax is not available.